# deploy cloudfoundry using bosh didn't make any system organization

Tags: cloud-foundry

When I deploy Cloudfoundry on AWS using bosh. It seems like there is no system organization.

refrenced instruction is here: https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/deploying/aws/index.html

After deployment completed and Login I got this:

```
    ~$ cf login --skip-ssl-validation -a https://api.xxx.net -u xxx -p xxx
    API endpoint: https://api.xxx.net
    Authenticating...
    OK

    API endpoint:   https://api.xxx.net (API version: 2.69.0)
    User:           xxx
    No org or space targeted, use 'cf target -o ORG -s SPACE'
```

Is there any way to find out what went wrong?

Comment: Surprising... I would try to create an organization by hand. `cf create-org my-org`. In case this fails, you may know what has happened.

Comment: In that case, I got this: 
`org xxx already exists`

Comment: But `cf orgs` comes with `No orgs found`

Comment: are you logged in as admin? Maybe you just cannot see the system org. As a normal user you usually cannot see the system org. You must first be given access with `cf set-org-role <your_user_name> system OrgManager`

Comment: Result is : Organization xxx not found. It's so weird...

Comment: my cf-stub.yml is like this. is it help to figure out what's wrong? https://gist.github.com/anonymous/d5e41fb9a1fdf971c6ceb5da836cd3c7

Comment: you must be org admin to assign the OrgManager role to other users. I this is a standard bosh-lite installation, then user/pass is admin/admin.

Answer (score 0):

I found these tables is empty:

```
ccdb.organizations_manager;
ccdb.organizations_users;
```

when i insert data like this:

```
insert organizations_users values (1,1);
insert organizations_managers values (1,1);
```

Then it works fine. cf login can log into the system organization.
Which installation step is failed or misconfigured?

Comment: Glad this works for you, but you should not directly edit the cloudcontroller database. Log in as admin and assign those rights via the cf cli.